# ¿Se puede tener un objeto Json con esta estructura?

Tags: json, r

Resulta que estoy leyendo un archivo.json por medio de la librería rjson

```
   library(rjson)
   json <- read_json("response_api_demanda.json")
```

pero al momento de consultarlo, queda de esta manera:

```
> json
[[1]]
[[1]]$agente
[1] "EPMC"

[[1]]$mercado
[1] "R"

[[1]]$fecha
[1] "2023-01-01"

[[1]]$demanda
[1] 2363031475

[[1]]$limite_inf
[1] 700141220

[[1]]$limite_sup
[1] 4025921730
```

Y lo necesitaría de esta forma, para posteriormente pasarlo como parámetro a un stored procedure.

```
[
  {
    "agente": "EPMC",
    "mercado": "R",
    "fecha": "2023-01-01",
    "demanda": 2363031474.6229,
    "limite_inf": 700141219.7127,
    "limite_sup": 4025921729.533
  }
  ]
```

He intentando con varias librerías, pero no me entrega el formato que necesito, por ejemplo probé con

```
json <- paste(json, collapse = " ")
json <- fromJSON(json)
 pero me lo entrega de esta manera
list(agente = \"EPMC\", mercado = \"R\", fecha = \"2023-01-01\", demanda = 2363031474.6229, limite_inf = 700141219.7127, limite_sup = 4025921729.533)
```

Existe la posibilidad de cambiar el formato?

Answer (score 1):

Tu `json` original se "deserializa" en un objeto como el siguiente:

```
objeto <- list(agente = "EPMC", 
               mercado = "R", 
               fecha = "2023-01-01", 
               demanda = 2363031474.6229, 
               limite_inf = 700141219.7127, 
               limite_sup = 4025921729.533)
```

Para reformular el `json` tal como lo muestras en tu ejemplo, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
toJSON(list(objeto), 
       pretty=TRUE, 
       auto_unbox=TRUE)
 
[
  {
    "agente": "EPMC",
    "mercado": "R",
    "fecha": "2023-01-01",
    "demanda": 2363031474.6229,
    "limite_inf": 700141219.7127,
    "limite_sup": 4025921729.533
  }
]
```

Comentarios:

- el parámetro `pretty` es solo estético, agrega espacios para hacer más "bonita" la salida, no deberías usarlo en realidad a la hora de generar el `json` final
- `auto_unbox` transforma los vectores de un solo elemento en un dato escalar
- Por lo que muestras en tu ejemplo, se trata una lista de objetos, de ahí que hagamos `list(objeto)`